# regex putting whole string in group 1

Tags: java, regex

Attempting to do regex in Java to split addresses into two columns in a database table. A string I would match on is:

102 Main St. BLDG 105

Group 1 should hold 102 Main St.

Group 2 should hold BLDG 105

Group 3 not really needed just not sure how else to do this.

Using the below everything is placed in group 1

```
(.+)(\s(APT|LOT|BLDG|UNIT|TRLR|SUITE|STE)*)
```

I use the groups in java to set the attributes.

**=====EDIT======**

Thanks for all of the the help from @WiktorStribiżew it has gotten me very close to what I am attempting to do.

The regex I am now using is:

```
(.+)\s((?:APT|LOT|BLDG|UNIT|TRLR|SUITE|STE).*)
```

Group 1 is not lazy I need it to consume odd instance where tokens occur twice in the string.

I am also not sure what the word boundary was doing and have it removed in my most recent code.

Here are my test cases

123 as St STE 5

120 LOT St LOT A100 <-- Why Group 1 is not lazy.

120 N. LOT St <-- This case fails
              <-- Group 1: 120 N. Group: 2 LOT St

100 LOT St LOT# as8080

123 LOT St <-- This is okay with a conditional I have in the code but would other wise split.

125 MERLOT Dr. LOT A800

Comment: Try `(.+?)(?:\\s*((?:APT|LOT|BLDG|UNIT|TRLR|SUITE|STE)\\s+\\d+).*)`

Comment: The first group matches the entire regex string. I don't know if that's what you're calling "group 1", or if you've already accounted for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the following regex with `String#matches`:

```
String p = "(.+?)\\s*(\\b(?:APT|LOT|BLDG|UNIT|TRLR|SUITE|STE)\\s+\\d+).*";
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/oW5tW4/2)

The `(?:...)` is a non-capturing group, thus, there is no special group for it.
The lazy matching `(.+?)` will match and capture into Group 1 all text up to the first space(s) followed with your alternatives. Then, Group 2 will hold one of the alternatives + whitespaces + digit(s).

## UPDATE

Here is a version of the regex that meets the requirements: 1) Group 1 is not lazy (it means, `matcher.group(1)` result should be trimmed from whitespace), 2) word boundary makes sure we do not match earlier at "LOTTERY":

```
^(.+)\s*(\b(?:APT|LOT|BLDG|UNIT|TRLR|SUITE|STE)\b.*)$
```

See [another demo](https://regex101.com/r/oY9bB8/3)

Comment: Is there a way to let anything after LOT or any of the tokens. I could have LOT A5. Thanks for the great explanation.

Comment: That is a matter of a slight adjustment: `String p = "(.+?)\\s*((?:APT|LOT|BLDG|UNIT|TRLR|SUITE|STE).*)";`.

Comment: I did not add anchors `^` and `$` as I assumed you are using String.matches(). Otherwise, add the ^ at the beginning and $  at the end.

Comment: Sorry a bit more explicit on my part would have helped. I did try that but it gives me the issue where something like 100 Melot St. is split to group 1: 100 Mer and group 2 lot St.

Comment: I added a word boundary `\b` before the alternation group. It should be enough to fix that kind of issues. I will update the demo once I am at my desktop.

Comment: Making the third group non-capturing is just a convenience; the reason the regex was failing is because it was *optional*.  And judging by @nerdlyist's last comment, that portion of the address really is optional (which it usually is, in my experience).

Comment: I have edit the question showing some test cases and results. Plus the current regex string I have.

Comment: I am bringing my son to a taekwondo lesson, I will be available in a couple of hours. If anyone else comes up with a better working solution, I'm fine with that.

Comment: I removed the answered just temporarily. If no one offers anything better I will put it back. @AlanMoore you are correct the second part is optional not everyone has them.

Comment: Please check [this `^(.+?)\s*(\b(?:APT|LOT|BLDG|UNIT|TRLR|SUITE|STE)\b.*)$` demo](https://regex101.com/r/oY9bB8/2) and let me know what exactly is not OK.